# kafka mongo conector is not working as expected

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Kafka connect (source) with mongo, the connect worker is functioning, but  it is not writing data to a Kafka topic, I am using the source connector and the following configuration file for the connector:

```
name=mongo-ff
tasks.max=1
connector.class =com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector
database=haifa
collection=alerts
key.converter = org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter = org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter

topic.prefix=someprefix
poll.max.batch.size=1000
poll.await.time.ms=5000

# Change stream options
pipeline=[]
batch.size=0
change.stream.full.document=updateLookup
```

but when I try to consume data from the topic:

```
 bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic someprefix  --from-beginning
```

I didn't get any data.

It seems as if it is not writing as expected.

a part of the log stack is :

```
    ... 3 more
[2020-01-22 17:19:52,727] INFO Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:20}] to localhost:27017 (org.mongodb.driver.connection:71)
[2020-01-22 17:19:52,732] INFO Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 6, 3]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=2854274} (org.mongodb.driver.cluster:71)
[2020-01-22 17:19:52,732] INFO Discovered cluster type of STANDALONE (org.mongodb.driver.cluster:71)
[2020-01-22 17:19:52,733] ERROR Expecting a single STANDALONE, but found more than one.  Removing localhost:27017 from client view of cluster. (org.mongodb.driver.cluster:101)
[2020-01-22 17:19:52,735] INFO Cluster ID: sZ64WgvDRBmrJnawsRJ_7A (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata:379)
[2020-01-22 17:19:52,756] INFO Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out (org.mongodb.driver.cluster:71)
[2020-01-22 17:20:02,647] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=mongo-fff-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:398)
[2020-01-22 17:20:02,648] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=mongo-fff-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:415)
[2020-01-22 17:20:12,649] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=mongo-fff-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:398)
[2020-01-22 17:20:12,649] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=mongo-fff-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:415)

getting some error:
ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=mongo-fff-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:177)
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27018, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connexion refusée (Connection refused)}}, {address=localhost:27019, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connexion refusée (Connection refused)}}]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:182)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AbstractMultiServerCluster.getDescription(AbstractMultiServerCluster.java:54)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.getConnectedClusterDescription(MongoClientDelegate.java:152)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.createClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:103)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.getClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:284)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:188)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.ChangeStreamIterableImpl.execute(ChangeStreamIterableImpl.java:203)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.ChangeStreamIterableImpl.access$000(ChangeStreamIterableImpl.java:53)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.ChangeStreamIterableImpl$1.cursor(ChangeStreamIterableImpl.java:128)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.ChangeStreamIterableImpl$1.iterator(ChangeStreamIterableImpl.java:123)
    at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.MongoSourceTask.createCursor(MongoSourceTask.java:236)
    at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.MongoSourceTask.start(MongoSourceTask.java:136)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:199)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[2020-01-22 18:29:09,590] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=mongo-fff-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:178)
[2020-01-22 18:29:09,593] INFO [Producer clientId=producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 30000 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer:1145)
[2020-01-22 18:29:19,482] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=mongo-fff-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:398)
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the worker's logs?

Comment: I will add the whole log stack to the post

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your expectations are not quite right.

In the configuration file, you have set the topic's prefix:

```
topic.prefix=someprefix
```

but you are trying to consume from a topic called `someprefix`:

```
 bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic someprefix  --from-beginning
```

Note that [`topic.prefix`](https://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/index.html#configuration-options) configuration parameter is not the name of the topic that will be created but it is just the prefix of it:

> **`topic.prefix`**
>
> Prefix to prepend to table names to generate the name of
>   the Kafka topic to publish data to, or in the case of a custom query,
>   the full name of the topic to publish to.
>
> **Type:** `string`
>
> **Default:** `“”`
>
> **Importance:** high

Therefore, if your database `haifa` has a table called `users` then the topic that will be created based on your configuration file will be named as `someprefixusers` (I suggest you to use a hyphen like `topic.prefix=someprefix-` so that the end topic name is more readable). Therefore, you will have to consume records from that topic:

```
 bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic someprefixusers  --from-beginning
```

**EDIT:**

You get a `Connection Refused` error which means that either your mongodb is not up and running or you are not connecting properly with the database.

Firstly, make sure that mongodb is up and running through `mongoclient`:

```
mongo mongoHost:mongoPort/dbname
```

Secondly, it seems that `connection.uri` is missing from your connector's configuration file.

Comment: you mean a collection no ? instead of a table, but it doesn't work either

Comment: @scalacode can you share the full list of your topics?

Comment: well I deleted all topics and i relaunched the connet worker and I notices that  it is not creating any new topic at kafka level bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper  localhost:2181 gives as a result
__consumer_offsets

Comment: @scalacode Can you post the full error trace reported in your logs?

Comment: done I added it at the bottom of my previous message